# How to translate these kind of phrases?

Tags: adjectives, translation

I am confused in translating some kind of phrases such as below :
Which one of the pairs is true? If both, What is the difference? and what is the meaning of the phrase? (I mean if I want to explain the phrase what I must say?)

- Security function requirement interfering actions
- Security function requirement interfered actions
- Security function requirement enforcing actions
- Security function requirement enforced actions

Update :
I want to translate the below paragraph in persian. But I don't understant the **...ing** words in the bold phrases return to which one of the words in back!

Note : SFR = Sequrity Function Requirement

> The purpose of this work unit is to supplement the details about the
>   **SFR-enforcing actions** (provided in work unit ADV_FSP.3-6) with a
>   summary of the remaining actions (i.e., **those that are not
>   SFR-enforcing**). This covers all **SFR-supporting** and **SFR-non-interfering**
>   actions, whether invokable through **SFR-enforcing TSFI** or through
>   **SFR-supporting** or **SFR-non-interfering** TSFI. Such a summary about all
>   **SFR-supporting** and **SFR-non-interfering actions** helps to provide a more
>   complete picture of the functions provided by the TSF, and is to be
>   used by the evaluator in determining whether an action or TSFI may
>   have been mis-categorised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -ing forms of enforce, interfere, and support are used here to create adjectives. For example,

> SFR-enforcing actions

refers to actions which enforce the SFR. Two simple and more familiar examples for this construction are the adjectives "ground-breaking" (derived from "to break ground"), and "breath-taking".

All four variants given in your question are in principle correct. However,
an

> SFR-enforced action

is an action that has been enforced by the SFR, as compared to an action that enforces the SFR (which would be an SFR-enforcing action).

Note that the hyphen is quite useful because it indicates that "SFR" and "enforcing" are joined together to form the adjective "SFR-enforcing". Finally, using the abbreviation SFR also makes the expression much easier to understand.